# Int32.TryParse Error

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error "invalid expression term 'int'" on the if statement below:

```
if(Int32.TryParse(result.Tables[0].Rows[i][26].ToString(), out int number)) 
{
    command.Parameters["@evalpoints"].Value = number;
}
else
{
    command.Parameters["@evalpoints"].Value = 0;
}
```

I've been staring at it for an hour and have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Use a compatible version of C#/VS (and make sure the project build settings does not select an "old" version of C#). `out int variable` - [Inline Out Variables](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1175809/Csharp-New-Inline-Out-Variables) - was added in C# 7.0.

Comment: Are you running this on Visual Studio 2017? That's a c# 7 feature

Comment: Umm so I found this question helpful. I'm not sure why it was closed as nrep or typo. It's easily reproducible and not a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using syntax to declare the out parameter variable inline while using it. This was only introduced in C# 7.0 in March 2017. If you are using an older compiler or have set your language version to be less than 7.0, then you will get the error described since it doesn't expect a new variable to be declared as a function parameter. You can get around this by expanding the code into two lines and declaring the out parameter separately - which was the way it had to be done before this feature was introduced:

```
int number;
if(Int32.TryParse(result.Tables[0].Rows[i][26].ToString(), out number))
// ...
```